# Choose \documentclass dependent on compiler

Tags: pdftex, htlatex

I am not able to compile this tex document

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello    
\end{document}
```

with htlatex. I am able to do this using pdflatex. If I choose article (see 2nd line) as documentclass, everything is fine. However, I'd like to have pdfs using scrartcl. How can I switch between documentclasses dependent on the compiler I use?

Comment: `\RequirePackage{ifpdf}\documentclass{\ifpdf scrartcl\else article\fi}`

Comment: However, if you want everything available with article, there's nothing stoping you from `\usepackage{scrbase}` with `article` class. That way, you have everything from `scrartcl` available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\documentclass{\ifpdf scrartcl\else article\fi}

\begin{document}
hello    
\end{document}
```

Or, may be (I don't know) it's better not to risk anything

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \documentclass{scrartcl}
\else
  \documentclass{article}
\fi

\begin{document}
hello    
\end{document}
```